# libinput config files don't work on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: xorg, touchpad, libinput

I have a 15 inch Dell xps running Ubuntu and for the life of me I can't get libinput to use my configs for the touchpad.

My config files are in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. I also tried to change the `40-libinput.conf` that is in there directly but even that does not work.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "False"
    Option "TappingDrag" "False"
    Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
EndSection
```

I also tried to reference the touchpad by its direct ID that I got from `xinput list`. What am I doing wrong here? I even tried putting the config in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`. Nothing worked, please help :(

PS: Of course I rebooted in between changes.

Comment: i will try to help can you try to create in dir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-libinput.conf , with  container of this lines:

Comment: i was have a config file for my old laptop touchpad , im no luck to find it , i suggest to create new Xorg configuration file try to enter the command  # Xorg -configure :0 , replace the new Xorg to X11 dir

Comment: A few points: 1) Nitpick: the configs are used by XServer, not libinput. libinput is a generic library used by Wayland compositors and XServer, and the configuration is up to them. 2) Xorg configs are notoriously a maze. I recommend against using them; instead, you can either α) use your DE settings to configure touchpad, or β) use `xinput` command directly, and put it to autostart *(since after XServer session restarted the changes made by `xinput` are lost)*. 3) Usually, you can find errors in Xorg config by looking at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` after XServer restarted *(e.g. after reboot)*.